# Comparison of equality used as Adjunct - As good/happy as

Tags: meaning, grammar, syntactic-analysis, comparatives

I came across this sentence in A Thousand Splendid Suns by Khaled Hosseini:

> As happy as she was about this pregnancy, his expectation weighed on her.

I was trying to parse this sentence and was trying to understand the meaning. I checked The Cambridge Grammar of The English Language (CaGEL) for any possible explanation, but of no help. I didn't find anything similar there. The possible meaning I derived from it is: *She was happy about this pregnancy by X amount, his expectation weighted on her by X amount.*

**Question 1:** Is my understanding about the meaning correct? And what is the possible explanation about the sentence structure? Any reference to CaGEL?

I then turned to COCA for similar sentences. But I got more confused. The sentences that made me confused are:

> As good as this burger tasted, he should have ordered two. [I think this sentence is semantically different to the sentence I found in the book. I think this sentence means *Because this burger tasted so goof, he should have ordered two*.]
>
> As good as the food is, it would be even better if the menu were scaled back so Silargorn could concentrate on the dishes that set him apart. [And I think this is semantically different to the other two. I think it means *Because the food is very good, it would be even better if ...*]

**Question 2:** What is meaning of the two sentences from COCA? And can you please parse these sentences? And reference from CaGEL?

Comment: “As happy as she” ~ “even though she was happy”

Comment: No, you haven't got the right meaning. Effectively, it's ***Although** she was [very] happy about this pregnancy, [nevertheless,] his expectation weighted on her*. The sense of the juxtaposition is that it's contextually assumed the two assertions (1: She's glad to be pregnant, and 2: She's worried about what he expects) are to some extent "conflicting", with the further implication that even though she's ***very*** glad, this isn't enough to dispel her concerns. But it's not really about both assertions being somehow ***to the same extent***.

Comment: Are you sure that the word in the sentence is *weighted* rather than ***weighed***? Because you also write *tasted so* ***goof*** in another quote, which seems like an obvious typo of *good*.

Comment: What @JasonBassford said. Obviously a typo

Comment: @JasonBassford and FF sorry a typo. I corrected it.

Comment: Don't confuse this construction with the truly "equatable, to the same degree" sense in, for example, ***As** you reap, **so** shall you sow.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks I got the meaning of the first sentence. But what about the last two sentences from COCA?

Comment: It's a comparative construction. In "As happy as she was about this pregnancy", the first "as" is an adverb modifying "happy" and the second a preposition introducing the comparative clause "she was about this pregnancy". Thus the two as's are in construction  together.

Comment: For my money, your *As good as this burger tasted, he should have ordered two* example is a ***misuse***. That one could more sensibly be expressed as ***Because** this burger tasted **so** good, he should have ordered two*.

Comment: (You still have some remaining typos.) In any case, *as happy as she was* could be thought of as *even though she was happy*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Or *given how good this burger tasted, he should have ordered two.*

Comment: @JasonBassford: Yeah, that's *much* better than my feeble attempt!

Comment: And what about the last sentence? @FumbleFingers

Comment: Ah I found this in Practical English Usage by Swan (2nd Edition) sec 71

Comment: @Man_From_India That one probably means something like *despite how good the food is, the menu should be scaled back*. But the actual wording as it's written is confusing. It's a poor sentence that doesn't clearly express its meaning without additional context. (It's not entirely clear what the referent of *it* is. What would be better? The food, the menu, or the dining experience?)

Comment: I think my first comment is on point for the last example: ***Although** the food is [**very**] good, it would be **even better** if the menu were scaled back*.